# Se puede crear una aplicacion con python+tkinter donde al ejecutar esta aplicacion lo primero que haga es pedir un password para poder abrirla

Tags: python, tkinter

lo que quiero es cuando traten de abrir esta aplicacion ,,la aplicacion misma me pida un password para poder utilizar todo lo que trae dentro,,no se si me hice explicar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear dos formularios en un mismo *script* de manera que el segundo sólo se muestre si se introduce la *contraseña correcta* en el primero.

Por ejemplo:

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror


def validar_pass(e):

    global pass_ok

    if pass_entry.get() == PASSWORD:

        pass_ok = True
        pass_app.destroy()

    else:

        showerror(title='ERROR', message='CONTRASEÑA ERRONEA')
        pass_entry.delete(0, END)



PASSWORD = '123456'
pass_ok = False

pass_app = Tk()

pass_entry = Entry(pass_app, justify='center', show='*', width=10)
pass_entry.pack()

pass_app.bind('<Return>', validar_pass)
pass_entry.focus_set()

pass_entry.mainloop()

if not pass_ok:
    sys.exit(0)


root = Tk()
# Configura tu aplicación principal
root.mainloop()
```

En el ejemplo hemos definido una constante `PASSWORD` que representa la contraseña correcta para abrir la *aplicación principal* y un formulario `pass_app` que muestra un *entry* identificado como `pass_entry`. Además hemos definido la variable global `pass_ok` que utilizaremos para indicar si la contraseña introducida por el usuario es correcta o no.

Mediante `pass_app.bind('<Return>', validar_pass)` conseguimos que se ejecute la función `validar_pass` al pusar la tecla *ENTER*. Si la contraseña es correcta esta función establece `pass_ok = True` y cierra el formulario (`pass_app.destroy()`).

Al cerrarse el formulario se ejecutan las instrucciones después de `pass_entry.mainloop()`, es decir, se comprueba:

```
if not pass_ok:
    sys.exit(0)
```

De manera que si la contraseña es incorrecta la aplicación se cierra (sería el caso de cerrar el formulario anterior presionando el botón [X]). Pero si la contraseña es correcta se ejecuta la aplicación principal:

```
root = Tk()
# Configura tu aplicación principal
root.mainloop()
```

**NOTA:** Idealmente deberías almacenar la contraseña encriptada de algún modo, ya que si alguien abre el *script* con un editor de texto podrá verla. No se mucho sobre el tema pero puedes complicarle las cosas a un eventual curioso utilizando las funciones predefinidas `ord` y `chr`:

La función `ord` toma como argumento un carácter `str` y devuelve un número entero `int`. La función `chr` realiza la operación contraria.

Si por ejemplo quieres que la contraseña sea `"123456"` abre una *consola Python* y ejecuta lo siguiente:

```
>>> pass_privada = '123456'
>>> pass_publica = [ord(i) for i in pass_privada]
>>> pass_publica
[49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54]
```

Ahora en tu código cambia `PASSWORD = '123456'` por `PASSWORD = [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54]`. Solamente queda redefinir la función `validar_pass` de la siguiente manera:

```
def validar_pass(e):

    global pass_ok

    if pass_entry.get() == ''.join([chr(i) for i in PASSWORD]): # <- Ojo

        pass_ok = True
        pass_app.destroy()

    else:

        showerror(title='ERROR', message='CONTRASEÑA ERRONEA')
        pass_entry.delete(0, END)
```

Un saludo!

Comment: Idealmente deberías almacenar la contraseña encriptada de algún modo, ya que si alguien abre el script con un editor de texto podrá verla.me explicas como seria esto por tienes razon ,,cualquiera que edita el scrip podra ver mi password,,como seria

Comment: No se mucho sobre el tema pero he editado la respuesta para explicar que puedes utilizar las funciones `ord` y `chr` para *ocultar* la contraseña y que no se vea a simple vista. Si quien "cotillea el código" sabe programar sacará la contraseña pero algo es algo. Un saludo.